PowerBI measure for forecasting accuracy
I have used an ARIMA time series prediction model on customers sales forecasting on a monthly basis for the next 12 month using past 6 years data, it looks like its fitting a moving average line for future dates. I want to evaluate the accuracy of this prediction in PowerBI.
I am not sure what's the best way to write the DAX formula for it. For example, if i predict the sales to be $99 or $101, and the actual is $100, the accuracy is easy to calculate (1 - (abs(variance)/actual)), which is 99%.
However, if the variance is too big, lets say, forecast is $2000, while actual is -$100(a return), its clearly a bad prediction, but if i use above formula, the accuracy would be like more than 2000% or something.
My current formula:
Accuracy =
RETURN
IF(
ISBLANK([Total Forecast]) || ISBLANK([Total Sales]),
BLANK(),
1 - DIVIDE(AbsoluteError, [Total Sales], 0)
)
